# HTML CSS Show Text box on hovering

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

What I'm looking for is that when I hover over an image or text it will automatically shows a box that contains a text related to that image. As follows:

**CSS** :

```
.owners{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    border:0px solid #ff9d2a;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;

}
    span.own1{
        background:#F8F8F8;
        border: 5px solid #DFDFDF;
        color: #717171;
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 250px;
        width:310px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        line-height: 20px;
        position:absolute;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        top: auto;
        left:auto;
        display:none;
        padding:0 0px;


    }

    p.own{
        margin:0px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    p.own:hover span{
        display:block;
    }
```

**HTML** :

```
<div class="owners">

<table width="100%" height="100%" align="center" border="1">
   <tr><td width="%" valign="top">
<p class="own"><img src="images/avater.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
<br />
<font style="font-size:15px;">Employee Name</font><span class="own1">some text here should be shown here</span></p>
</td></tr>
   <tr><td width="%" valign="top">
<p class="own"><img src="images/avater.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
<br />
<font style="font-size:15px;">Employee Name</font><span class="own1">some text here should be shown here</span></p>
</td></tr>
</table>

</div>
```

The output for the above codes is a table that contains list of employee images and their names. So when I hover the mouse on top of them, a box shows that contains the text related to it BUT they are shown behind the images and names, by that I mean I am looking to make this box stand in front of the images not behind them. I hope this makes sense! I've tried changing `position:absolute` and `position:fixed` but none works as needed!

You can check this also : http://jsfiddle.net/g1o8vyqd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1o8vyqd/1/)

Just add the code and you should confirm there is no **z-index** higher than your hover element.

```
z-index:9;
```

to:

```
 p.own:hover span{
        display:block;
        z-index:9;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `z-index:1` to raise the element above the rest:

```
p.own:hover span {
    display:block;
    z-index:1
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1o8vyqd/3/

---

Note, also, that your markup is not very good: besides the fact that `table` is being used incorrectly (it's for [tabular data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data)), you are using the [font tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), which is **obsolete**. (In fact, it was deprecated in HTML ***4***)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
p.own{
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

p.own:hover span{
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alihamra, It sounds like you are looking for a tooltip. I would recommend cleaning up your code like the previous answers/comments outlined and then trying to utilize something like this: http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip.

Thanks